Funny Italian movie about two people

I watched a part of this movie on T.V., so I have no idea which year
it was released.
It looked like it was a good, legal HD print.
The movie is in color and set someplace in Italy.
I'm pretty sure it was dubbed into English because it was very
visible that the dialogues and lip movements did not sync.
It's about two people, and up until to the point I watched, it was
about two people (men) trying to find a job – one of them was a "poet", I do not know what the other was.
From the point where I watched it, the two people were running out of
some woods and into a house, which later on is revealed to be the house
of the other person's (non-poet's) uncle. I did not see the uncle
after that. The next day, the two people set out in search of a job.
I remember one of them wanted to open a shop, and when he went to the
realtor to rent a building, he accidentally dropped a flower pot on
the realtor, thus slimming his chances of opening a shop. Then, he was
chased by the realtor, and once he was out of sight, he knocked over
a pretty girl (a teacher, I suppose) and fell over her.
The only way I can describe the two characters is that both of them wore a top hat and were dressed in suits all the time.
I think the uncle owned a horse, though I'm not sure.

That's all I remember. Does anybody know what this movie is?

Were these two people both male? Any idea what they looked like? Do you remember, when you watched it? Was it in colour etc.?

Yes, it was in color, and both were men.

When did YOU watch it though ? It may make a difference if it was 10 years ago or yesterday. Any physical description for these characters ?

I watched it last week.

But I don't know if you know this, Indian TV does air really old movies too.

I have found the name of the movie. It's Life is Beautiful (1997), where in the beginning:

In 1939, Jewish-Italian Guido Orefice comes into Arezzo, Italy, ultimately to open a book store. In the meantime, he will work as a waiter at the hotel restaurant where his Uncle Eliseo is the maitre d'. In town, he meets a school teacher named Dora, who he calls Princess and who comes from a wealthy Italian family. For him, it's love at first sight. 

As it seems, I only watched a small portion and it was only now that I realized the movie was about the Holocaust.

Wow. The only part you remember from this film is the only part I don't. :O [Added.]
